# Sky and atmosphere not available in v. 2.9?

Tags: rendering, skybox

guys. I am initiating on blender so I just downloaded the latest version (2.9).

I am attending to an online course on 3D modelling and animation, but the video lectures were recorded using Blender 2.7 interface.

I need to render sky and atmosphere. In the video lecture, there is a check box for this feature when sun light is chosen.

However, I cannot find such an option in my latest version. I have alreade googled it, but got nothing.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you!

Comment: Every past version of blender is still available to download. If your course is using 2.7X, why struggle with 2.9 with no prior knowledge of the software to begin with?

Comment: also be careful that some options are available in Cycles but not in Eevee

Comment: I think this option is only available in the blender internal render engine, which doesn't exist anymore in newer versions.

Comment: Hi, @Timaroberts. Actually I always try to keep updated with softwares using theirs latest stable versions. It wouldn't be an actual strugle if the feature were available, since a simple search in google would be enough to solve my problem. However, as it semms, Blender 2.9 no longer has the feature of rendering sky and atmosphere, so this is a setback instead of progress of the software (from my point of view)...

Comment: Hi, @Gorgious. That was exactly my fear. And I think you are right... =/

Comment: Thank you, @moonboots, for your highlights.

Comment: To answer your question, the feature is available under "Sky Texture" when you are tweaking the environmental ligthing settings of the world. Keep in mind the latest addition, the Nishita model, only works with Cycles for now

Comment: Hi, @Gorgious, thank you for the tip. Searching a little bit more, I just found out I am not alone in this boat. The environment gets too clear and whitened when I apply the atmosphere, no matter if I render in with Cycles or Eevee, exactly as described here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194119/how-does-the-sky-texture-work-in-2-9

Comment: Long story short, it is somehow physically correct but it will blow most scenes with its default values. Decrease the strength of the background node to something like 0.1 or lower to get a decent exposure in an open environment

Comment: Hi, @Gorgious. It works! Thank you!